# Unable to use or cast a constructor as a fn

Tags: constructor, casting, rust, compiler-warnings, higher-order-functions

I want to write something like this:

```
use std::{iter, ops};

struct Idx(usize);

fn get_inds() -> iter::Zip<iter::Map<ops::RangeFrom<usize>, fn(usize) -> Idx>, ops::RangeFrom<usize>> {
    (0..).map(Idx).zip(0..)
}
```

However, this fails to compile:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
6 |>         (0..).map(Idx).zip(0..)
  |>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
note: expected type `std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Map<std::ops::RangeFrom<usize>, fn(usize) -> Idx>, std::ops::RangeFrom<usize>>`
note:    found type `std::iter::Zip<std::iter::Map<std::ops::RangeFrom<usize>, fn(usize) -> Idx {Idx::{{constructor}}}>, std::ops::RangeFrom<_>>`
```

I then cast the function:

```
fn get_inds() -> iter::Zip<iter::Map<ops::RangeFrom<usize>, fn(usize) -> Idx>, ops::RangeFrom<usize>> {
    (0..).map(Idx as fn(usize) -> Idx).zip(0..)
}
```

Which generates the following compiler warning. Why am I getting a warning? What is the proper way to use the constructor like this?

```
warning: can't cast this type, #[warn(const_err)] on by default
 --> src/main.rs:6:19
6 |>         (0..).map(Idx as fn(usize) -> Idx).zip(0..)
  |>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @Ruud `fn(A) -> B desugars to std::ops::Fn<(A,), Output=B>` — no, it does not. A function *implements* the `Fn*` traits, but they aren't the same. Just like `i32` *implements* `Add`, but is not desugared to `Add`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bogus warning caused by recent changes to the compiler's constant evaluator. See [#33452](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33452), [#33291](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/33291), etc. I wouldn't worry about it, but it's worth submitting a bug to the Rust repo so it can be fixed.